# Redirecting Mobile Devices to a Mobile Sub Domain

Tags: javascript, mobile, web

I am creating a website which I want to be mobile friendly, so I have decided to create a sub-domain that hosts a mobile compatible site. One issue I am having is re-directing the users who are on mobile to this sub-domain.

Using JavaScript, how would I detect the device and re-direct them to the sub-domain?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code. We solve problems, not write code for you.

Comment: I've tried this code:
    <script type="text/javascript">
     if (screen.width <== 800) {
      window.location = "http://m.SITENAME.com";
     } else {
      window.location = "/SiteDocuments";
     }
    </script>

Comment: It would make much more sense to do this with your server as a 302 redirect than in the browser.

Comment: With the 302 redirect, how would I detect if it was a mobile device?

Comment: Screen is not a predefined constant in JS which is why screen.width fails. Use window instead with inner or outerWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better option would be responsive website, much better user experience. and what if user wants to view actual version not mobile?

also redirect should be handled on server side not browser, in that manner website wouldn't load twice which is UX killer.

with php you can do something like

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to detect mobile using screen size. Using JavaScript, find the user agent. If the UA is of mobile, redirect them. There are a lot of plugins for this. [`redirection_mobile.js`](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site) is a utility script that covers a basic scenario for redirecting your website to a mobile verison through JavaScript.

You just need to call this script this way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="redirection-mobile.js"></script>
        <script>
            SA.redirection_mobile();
        </script>
    </head>
```